# Put xsl:value-of... inside CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to put the values that I get over an Iteration into CDATA Field. Is there any possibility to do this in XSLT?

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTest.xsl"?>
<pages>
  <page>
      <title>New Title</title>
      <id>4782</id>
      <timestamp>2012-09-13 13:15:33</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>kf</username>
        <id>2</id>
      </contributor>
      <text xml:space="preserve"> 
      some text
    </text>
 </page>
 </pages>
```

My XSL File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
    <content>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
        <alias><xsl:value-of select="title"/></alias>
        <introtext><xsl:value-of select="text"/></introtext>
        <created><xsl:value-of select="timestamp"/></created> //This value in a CDATA Field
        <created_by><xsl:value-of select="contributor/username"/></created_by>
        <modified_by><xsl:value-of select="contributor/username"/></modified_by>
    </content>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So basically I want the timestamp field value to be in a CDATA Field so that it basically will look like this in the end:

```
<created><![CDATA[2015-04-24 15:07:40]]></created>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why?  There's absolutely no difference between `<created>2015-04-24 15:07:40</created>` and `<created><![CDATA[2015-04-24 15:07:40]]></created>` as the content doesn't contain any characters that would need to be escaped.

Comment: I needed it because I import that file through an extension to my website. And the extension can only operate with the CDATA format. But thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Bizarre - I think you need to report this bug to the extension's authors.  If they want to parse XML they should use an XML parser (which won't care whether it's CDATA or not).  If they're violating this aspect of the XML spec then who knows what other aspects they're also messing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="created"/>`.

Comment: Yes worked perfectly fine thank you so much :) Question marked as solved !